# How to pre-fill a PDF online?

Tags: forms, pdf, pdf-generation, fpdf, pdflib

I start with dynamic data, and an empty PDF file to be filled.
How could I fill up the pdf using the dynamic data ?

---

EDIT :
I found a way to fill up the pdf with [FPDF.org](http://fpdpf.org) and a [plugin](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script93.php).

1. First, add form fields to your PDF using softwares such as Acrobat Pro or LiveCycle, and prepare the PDF online or offline using PDFtk : `pdftk modele.pdf output modele2.pdf`
2. Place data into arrays and fill the pdf with JS following the plugin instructions

Here it is, we get our PDF filled!

Now, I just need to flatten the form, in order to prevent the user to change the field options. Is there a way to do it, using either FPDF or PDFlib which is installed on my shared host?

Answer (score 0):

You can use pdftk to do that. eg.

```
pdftk form.pdf fill_form data.fdf output out.pdf flatten
```

or:

```
pdftk form.filled.pdf output out.pdf flatten
```

Comment: Unfortunately, pdftk can not be installed on my shared host. I can only rely on PDFlib, or any PHP based script...